# xcode storyboard stackview内での割合を指定したい

Tags: xcode, macos, storyboard

xcode storyboardを使用中です。
stackview内でボタンを２つ横並びで用意しました。現在は両方に同じwidthが適応されています。
これらの二つのボタン幅を3：1の割合で表示したいです。